# seriate node js how close connection

Tags: node.js, node-mssql, node-seriate

I have written a query to select rows in table using seriate, now the query is able to fetch the results but the command is not exiting unless I do ctrl + c in the git bash window.
Is there anyway to close the connection and come out of the session once the insert query is successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to use `sql.closeConnection()` after getting the results. Found it by trying the steps in interactive mode - node REPL.

Answer (score 0):

To end a process successfully use `process.exit(0)` or `process.exit(1)` (or any error code that makes sense for your app) if you encountered an error

Comment: I was not asking about how to exit the nodejs process but how to close the connection. Got the solution now :) Thanks